# How can I read local html files on my 1st Edition Nook?

Tags: html, nook

I know that the [1st Edition Nook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes_%26_Noble_Nook_1st_Edition) (OS version 1.7) does not have the capability to read **`.html`** files via the ebook reader. However, it seems to be able to read local **`.html`** files from the browser. I know this because the default home page is `file:///android_assets/browser.html`. However, I cannot seem to find **`.html`** files that I've added to the **`my documents/`** folder via the browser. I've tried the following URLs to access the **`my documents/`** folder:

- `file:///my documents`
- `file:///my%20documents`
- `file:///My%20nook`
- `file:///mnt/us`
- `file:///mnt/dc/us`

Those URLs return an error page with text like the following:

> #### Web Page Not Available
>
> The Web page at file:///my%20documents could not be loaded as:
>
> The requested file was not found. /my documents

If I can find the URL to the **`my documents/`** folder, I'll be able to get the path to my local **`.html`** files. If the **`my documents/`** directory is correctly loaded in the browser, an error message like the following will appear:

> #### Web Page Not Available
>
> The Web page at file:///some/path/to/my%20documents could not be loaded as:
>
> Is a directory.

I know I could probably root my nook to figure out the file structure, but I'd rather not do that since it requires a lot of work.

I know I could also convert my **`.html`** documents to an ebook using [`pandoc`](http://pandoc.org/), but the **`.html`** files I'm working with don't convert very cleanly unfortunately, so they would require a lot of manual editing.

Comment: I would still love to find the answer to this problem, but I ended up converting the **`.html`** files to an ebook using [calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/). It was pretty easy: I just added the *Table of Contents* **`.html`** to Calibre, selected it, clicked *Convert books*, and followed the steps.